# ASP.net MVC pass some data from view to controler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

In view I have ListBox so user can select some data. I also have MultiSelectList for same reason.
User can choose some date from MultiSelectList  or he doesn't have to (he can leave that field  blank). And that worked fine.
I've decided to add TextBox so user can enter data if he wants. Now when user enters data to TextBox and doesn't choose any data from MultiSelectList  everything is fine.

But ! If user chooses data from MultiSelectList  and leaves TextBox empty I get this error:

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'CompetitionId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be       of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
```

And that error is showed for LisBox.

I have same problem with another view / controller. I've enabled option for user to upload image, and if he doesn't click on choose image, and uploads image I get same error for another ListBox in that view .

Please help me to slove this. Here is code for first controller  / view

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Competitions = new SelectList(_competitionRepository.GetAllCompetitionsAndNotActive().AsEnumerable(),
                                              "CompetitionId", "Name");
        ViewBag.Tags = new MultiSelectList(_tagRepository.GetAllTags().AsEnumerable(), "TagId", "Name");



        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Advert/Create

    [HttpPost, Authorize]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(AdvertDTO advertDTO, int [] tags, int competitionId, string inputTags)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Advert</legend>


    <div class="editor-label">
        Choose Competition
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CompetitionId", (SelectList)ViewBag.Competitions, new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Choose  Competitions...", style="width:350px;" } )           
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompetitionId)
    </div>      
    ....     
    @Html.ListBox("Tags", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Tags, new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Choose  Tags...", style="width:350px;" })


       <br/>
       <label>OR</label>
       <input type="text" id="inputTags" name="inputTags" style="width: 325px" />

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create"  />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

**EDIT**
Long story short I want user to be able tu submit empty fields

Comment: Can you post the rendered markup for the DropDownList?

Comment: Can you show the @model line of view? Because you use ViewBag to pass those two lists, so what is your model?

Comment: @HyperN No, post the actual markup containing the input tags that are rendered to the page when you access it in your browser.

Comment: For DropDown:
`<select class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Choose  Competitions..." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CompetitionId must be a number." data-val-required="The CompetitionId field is required." id="CompetitionId" name="CompetitionId" style="width:350px;"><option value="1">Imagine Cup</option>
<option value="2">ASC</option>
</select>   `

Comment: For MultiSelectList
`<select class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Choose  Tags..." id="Tags" multiple="multiple" name="Tags" style="width:350px;"><option value="1">C#</option>
<option value="2">.net</option>
<option value="4">java</option>
</select>`

Comment: Also at what exact point is the error occurring?  Is it during the HttpPost Create() method, or the HttpGet Create() method when it tries to return to the view?

Comment: And for TextBox: `<input type="text" id="inputTags" name="inputTags" style="width: 325px" />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"  />
        </p>
`

Comment: When I click submit button, so during HttpPost Create()

Comment: And this is same for the second view/controller in which I upload file, if I don't upload it, I get exception at DropDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it ... there were few stupid mistakes I didn't see :/ sorry for all the trouble

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is bad

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompetitionId)
```

Can you comment it?

Comment: When I comment it for some reason I have problems with MultiSelectList and tags

Answer (score 0):

I think your action is actually posting back all the values from the select list.  If you want to only post back a selected item you could try something like

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompetitionId, (SelectList)ViewBag.Competitions, new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Choose  Competitions...", style="width:350px;" } )
```

Comment: I've tried it but same error `The ViewData item that has the key 'CompetitionId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.`